# One Directional Combinations in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can i get the expected result?
Note i dont know the length of first list. Every inner list inside the main list has the same length(this case its 3).

```
arr = [[1, 'ok', 3.1],
   [4, 'done', 4.5],
   [3, 'hola', 0.3],
   [23, 'mew', 45.7]]
```

Expected Output :

```
# [[1, 'ok', 3.1], 
# [[1, 'ok', 4.5],
# [1, 'ok', 0.3],
# [1, 'ok', 45.7],
# [1, 'done', 3.1],
# [1, 'done', 0.3],
# [1, 'done', 45.7],
# [1, 'hola', 3.1],
# [1, 'hola', 4.5],
# [1, 'hola', 45.7],
# ...........
# ...........
# [[3, 'ok', 3.1],
# [[3, 'ok', 4.5],
# [3, 'ok', 0.3],
# [3, 'ok', 45.7],
# SO ON
```

Comment: use pprint? https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html?highlight=pprint#pprint.pprint

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the cartesian product of a series of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may combine [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

- `zip` is make lists of values at the same indexes : `[1,4,3,23], ['ok', 'done', ..`
- `product` is to make a cartesian product between all

  ```
  product([1,2], ['a', 'b']) => [1,'a'], [1,'b'], [2,'a'], [2,'b']
  ```

```
from itertools import product
arr = [[1, 'ok', 3.1],
   [4, 'done', 4.5],
   [3, 'hola', 0.3],
   [23, 'mew', 45.7]]

res = product(*zip(*arr))

for a in res:
  print(a)
```

Comment: @That'sEnam You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)